# How should I build a skid foundation for my shed?

Tags: foundation, shed

I am planning a 14 x 20 shed, going to build on a 4x4 skid foundation, I can only get 16ft 4x4, what is the best method for the 4 feet left?  Should I make all the joints at one end or use 2, 10 ft 4x4 and double the joist in that section?

Answer (score 1):

I'd opt for using the 10 ft 4X4's with a sistered joint in the middle. You could sister the joint with a 2 ft length of 2X4 on each side, so one 8 ft 2X4 would do both skids.  Be sure to taper or bevel the ends of the 4X4's so it will "skid".

Comment: When you taper the ends, also drill a large hole a couple inches back, so you can hook on a pull rope.